# How to calculate 'np.where' for irregular dataframe datas?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string, sorting

I have following dataframes:

```
(df1)    (df2)    (df2)
one      one      one
two      two      three
three    two      four
five     three    five
six      five     six
seven    seven    seven
         nine     nine
         six      ten 
                  three
```

mycode:

```
comparison_values = df2.values == df1.values
rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)
```

i get error as below:

i understand there is no enough value to unpack as it says but
i want to compare it without error. is it possible to compare df1 with other irregular df2 columns ?

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

i get a good output if i compare with correct datas after removing those extra rows in df2

```
[true true ]
[true False]
[False False]
[False true ]
[False False ]
[true true ]
```

but not for df2 irregular data. its gives False for all irregular data.

```
[False]
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Have you printed `comparison_values` to see what it actually contains?

Comment: it gives straight error as false. i will update my thread

Comment: The second `df2` is `df3` or the expect output?

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, it sounds like you want `isin`.  E.g. `df1.isin(df2)`.

Comment: no the both df2 are just datas i want true false by comparing df1 single column with df2 two irregular columns

Comment: @Chris it gives single column instead of 2 dimensional column

Comment: @Titanium – can you clarify your inputs then please?  The question looks like there are two dfs called `df2`.  It can't be two columns of the same df as they have different lengths, which `pandas` doesn't allow.

Comment: i have updated the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input data looks like that:

```
>>> df1
       0
0    one
1    two
2  three
3   five
4    six
5  seven

>>> df2
       0      1
0    one    one
1    two  three
2    two   four
3  three   five
4   five    six
5  seven  seven
6   nine   nine
7    six   ten
8    NaN   three
```

You can reindex df1 with the index of df2 to have the same size:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(df2.index)
mask = df1.values == df2.values
rows, cols = np.nonzero(~mask)  # or np.where
```

Output result:

```
>>> mask
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False]])

>>> rows, cols
(array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]),
 array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]))

>>> df1[np.all(~mask, axis=1)]  # data1
       0
2  three
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN

>>> df2[np.all(~mask, axis=1)]  # data2
      0      1
2   two   four
6  nine   nine
7   six   ten
8   NaN  three
```

Comment: Wow thanks its working and can you please tell me how to iterate that rows and cols wihout getting 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds' ?

for item in zip(rows,cols):
        
    data1 = df1.iloc[item]
    data2 = df2.iloc[item]

Comment: i want to keep all false data. df1 has 14 rows and df2 has 17 rows thats why that error is poping. may be is it good idea to fill df1 with nan from df1-df2 values which is four. so if i insert 4 nan in df1 at last the error goes i guess. can you help ? thank you

Comment: But in `mask`, you can have `[False, True]` or `[True, False]` (any). You want only `[False, False]` (all), it's right?

Comment: yeah thats right right and i updated the previous comment

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look at the end of 'Output result'. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Thank dude, everything is working ! i actually i need df2 false, so i dont need to iterate df1. my bad

Comment: Hai dude, can you please answer this thread ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285695/how-to-check-df1-rows-with-all-single-rows-of-another-df2-column-to-check-if-sam?noredirect=1#comment120684944_68285695