# How to check df1 rows with all single rows of another df2 columns to check if same in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe, sorting

I have seen many codes like this:

```
mergedStuff = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')

or

mask = df1.reindex(df2.index).values == df2.values
```

but above gives only if a same row is present in its opposite rows its not comparing to every row

for ex:

```
 df1 contains:
  
  0

  hello  
  how
  are
  you 
  guys
  system

  df2 contains:
  
  0             1   ........ n

  how           hello        you
  hello         guys         hello
  you           system       how 
  are           you          you
  guys          hello        hello
  system        how          how
  hello         are          system
```

UPDATE: final output column after comparing df2.isin(df1):

```
  #NOTE ! below output are manually entered, not from real output
  #        but i know this is how it gives.
  false   True   false
  false   false  false
  false   false  false
  false   false  false
  false   false  false
  false   false  false
  false   false  false      #only second column and second row are 
                                      #  true, because 
                                       # it matches 
                                       # the same row
```

but what i want is i want to cross check each df1 rows with df2 rows.

expected output:

```
  True  True  True
  True  True  True
  True  True  True
  True  True  True
  True  True  True
  True  True  True
  True  True  True    #i want true for all Because every rows has 
                       # the same word.
```

UPDATE2:

However if i run like this then it gives expected output:

df2[2].isin(df1[0])

```
 True
 True
 True
 True
 True
 True
 True  # 2nd column of df2 compared with df1 and gives good output.
        # but if i give without index it gives crap.
```

If you want to help, here is the input for testing:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: 
['hello','how','are','you','guys','system']})

   df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 0: 
  ['how','hello','you','hello','guys','hello',
    'you','system','how','are','you','you' 
     'guys','hello','hello','system','how',
      'how','hello','are','system'],

    1: ['how','you','you','hello','guys',
      'hello','you','system','how','are','you','you' 
       'guys','hello','hello','system',
       'how','hello','hello','are','system'] ,

      2: ['how','you','you','are','guys',
     'hello','you','system','you','are','guys','you' 
          'guys','hello','hello','system',
        'how','hello','hello','are','system']
            })
```

Finally this one is working:

```
new = np.isin(df2, df1)
rows, cols = np.nonzero(~new)

#or

new = np.isin(df2, df1, invert=True)
rows, cols = np.nonzero(new)


x2 = []

for item in zip(rows,cols):
    x2.append(df2.iloc[item])
```

Comment: what about sorting them first?

Comment: What do you want exactly? The list of words that doesn't appear?

Comment: yeah, if you run that code, error occures and i understand the error but dont know how to solve. after getting all false values then i can give a color to that value in excel, thats why.

Comment: @Corralien Hi, can you please check this thread and answer if possible ? my humble request. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314626/how-to-extract-particular-column-of-docx-and-save-it-to-dataframe-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.in1d`:

```
>>> df2.apply(lambda x: np.in1d(x, df1[0]))
        0      1      2
0    True   True   True
1    True   True   True
2    True   True   True
3    True   True   True
4    True   True   True
5    True   True   True
6    True   True   True
7    True   True   True
8    True   True   True
9    True   True   True
10   True   True   True
11  False  False  False
12   True   True   True
13   True   True   True
14   True   True   True
15   True   True   True
16   True   True   True
17   True   True   True
18   True   True   True
19   True   True   True
```

**Update**: list of missing words

```
>>> set(np.extract(mask == False, df2))
{'youguys'}
```

Comment: Wow thanks buddy ! working great but can you please tell just one more thing ?

i have updated in the main query

Answer (score 2):

try [`pandas.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'], columns=['column1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(['hello', 'are', 'you', 'how'], columns=['column1'])

df1["column1"].isin(df2["column1"])

# 0    True
# 1    True
# 2    True
# 3    True
# Name: column1, dtype: bool
```

NOTE: I am afraid it is `O(n*m)` complexity that means for every element of df1 you are iterating df2, although I don't know the actual implementation. The faster way is to sort both the columns and check for equality.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'], columns=['column1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(['hello', 'are', 'you', 'how'], columns=['column1'])

df1.sort_values(['column1'], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
df2.sort_values(['column1'], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

df1['column1'] == df2['column1']
```

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: column1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new = np.isin(df2, df1)
rows, cols = np.nonzero(~new)

#or

new = np.isin(df2, df1, invert=True)
rows, cols = np.nonzero(new)


x2 = []

for item in zip(rows,cols):
    x2.append(df2.iloc[item])
```