# How to extract particular column of docx and save it to dataframe in python?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, string, dataframe

I have following two tables in a docx

```
  #Table one
  
  item components Description  qty  

   1    laptop      asus        2

        processor   i5-1135G7 
                    Processor 

        ram         8 GB DDR4 3200MHz 

  #Table 2


  item components Description  qty  

   1    battery      lethium 
                     ion  

        gpu         rtx 2060 super 

  #Table 'n'
```

i want to extract only the desciption from all n number of tables.

so far i have tried the following code:

```
document = Document('test.docx')
tables = document.tables

tables = []
for table in document.tables:
    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            if cell.text:
                df[i][j] = cell.text
    tables.append(pd.DataFrame(df))
```

tables:

```
   item components Description  qty 
  
   1    laptop      asus        2

        processor   i5-1135G7 
                    Processor 

        ram         8 GB DDR4 3200MHz 

  item components Description  qty  

   1    battery      lethium 
                     ion  
        gpu         rtx 2060 super 

  #rest of other tables
```

i want all tables array into dataframe with heading of description.
expected output:

```
   Description
 
   i5-1135G7 
   Processor 
   8 GB DDR4 3200MHz     
   lethium ion  
   rtx 2060 super
```

Comment: Can you share your test.docx, please?

Comment: is it working bro ? i hope you got the doc

Comment: As your example is not the same as your document, which table(s) do you want to get?

Comment: is it possible to get all the tables ? i learnt that docx read the table as text. so its hard to extract description alone from the docx but is there any alternate solution for this ?

Comment: oh..ok sure. no problem, thanks for trying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234714/discussion-between-titanium-and-corralien).

Comment: This is my new question and its really good one. please help if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327690/how-to-extract-full-text-from-a-list-with-fuzzywuzzy

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to extract data from Word but if you copy your table from Word to Notepad and save it as plain text, you can do:

```
import re

with open('table4.txt') as fp:
    data = []
    for line in fp.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line != '':
            data.append(re.split('\t+', line))

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```

```
>>> df.loc[df['Description'].notna(), 'Description']

0              3 Cell Li-Polymer Internal Battery, 45Wh
1          65W AC Adapter PCC (3pin)-India (USB Type C)
2      Keyboard Backlit Black with Texture English (IN)
3                                   Publication-English
4                                               W10 Pro
5                             Windows 10 Pro 64 English
6                              E14G2&R14G2 i5-1135G7 IG
7     14.0" FHD(1920x1080) TN AntiGlare 220nits Non-...
9                                 BIOS Absolute Enabled
11                            Premier Support Asset Tag
12                                    No vPro Certified
13                                No Fingerprint Reader
14                                        No Carry Case
15                                 No CO2 Neutral Label
16                                   Relationship Model
17                                       Windows 10 Pro
18                                                   IN
19                          PUB ENG/TC/JPN/KOR/IDN/THAI
20                                             Standard
21                                              Core i5
22                                          Windows GML
23                               WIN N-AMT Y-dTPM Y-ABS
24                            WLAN Misc Parts-WLAN Card
25                                                  IND
26                                              Low End
27                          E14G2 Dcover BK ABS Texture
28                           KBL_ID_IND_ENG_KBLANG_4009
30                          WARRANTY 3Y Premier Support
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Titanium. Did you have time to test the solution?

Comment: Hey thanks buddy for you work, i have worked alternative solution for this.