# How to extract full text from a list with fuzzywuzzy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, fuzzywuzzy

Below is my code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

check = open("text.txt","a")
    
MIN_MATCH_SCORE = 30
heard_word = 'i5-1135G7 '
possible_words = check

guessed_word = [word for word in possible_words if fuzz.ratio(heard_word, word) >= 
MIN_MATCH_SCORE]
print ('this one - ', guessed_word)
```

expected output:

```
 11th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 Processor
```

is it possible to get that whole sentence in expected output just by giving 'i5-1135G7 ' alone ? is there any alternate solution to get what i expect ? Thank you in advance.

below is the link for text.txt
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mo3qFmeOAqa3WPPyg8SpeFVSjDx7AQBj/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To offset longer sentences and to make sure overlap at word level you should rather use `token_set_ratio`. Also if you want full word overlap then increase the `MIN_MATCH_SCORE` to close to 100.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

  
MIN_MATCH_SCORE = 90
heard_word = 'i5-1135G7'

possible_words = ['11th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 Processor (2.40 GHz,up to  4.20 GHz with Turbo Boost, 4 Cores, 8 Threads, 8 MB Cache)', 
                   'windows 10 64 bit', 'intel i7']
                   
print ([word for word in possible_words 
        if fuzz.token_set_ratio(heard_word, word) >= MIN_MATCH_SCORE])
```

Output:

```
['11th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 Processor (2.40 GHz,up to  4.20 GHz with Turbo Boost, 4 Cores, 8 Threads, 8 MB Cache)']
```

Comment: Hey thanks its working but can you please try this test.txt inside possible words variable ?
test.txt link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mo3qFmeOAqa3WPPyg8SpeFVSjDx7AQBj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: when i try that text.txt im getting '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'Windows 10 Pro 64', 'Windows 10 Pro 64', when i give 'windows 10' in heard_word.

Comment: Check the update, now you should have a decent result.

Comment: yeah im getting good result but i cant get rid of that 1,1,1,1,1,1 if i pass that test.txt in possible words. i only want that --->  ['11th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 Processor (2.40 GHz,up to  4.20 GHz with Turbo Boost, 4 Cores, 8 Threads, 8 MB Cache)']

please test with test.txt.

Answer (score 0):

#token_set_ratio works fine !
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

```
s = []
for l in df1.values:
    l = ', '.join(l)
    s.append(l)

s = ', '.join(s)    
main = [x for x in g if x]
MIN_MATCH_SCORE = 60
heard_word = 'i5-11th gen'
guessed_word = [word for word in main if fuzz.token_set_ratio(heard_word, 
word) >= MIN_MATCH_SCORE]
print ('this one - ', guessed_word)
```